# Iterating through a result set in shell

Tags: shell, unix, iteration, resultset

So I've searched quite a bit for this and I'm pretty new to Shell, 
I want to iterate over Resultset rows in SHELL script and for each row I want to execute some code using each column of the current row. 
Lets assume the resultset look like this.

```
Query                             Priority  Size 
---------------------------------------------------  
this is a sentence to execute      high    124400 
this is another example            low     15000000
...
```

So how do I manage to iterate over this Resultset and storing each column into his own variable? Here is an exemple for the first line:

```
var1="this is a sentence to execute"
var2="high"
var3=124400
#repeat process for next line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you could do:

- Extract your data into a delimited file (say, csv), if possible, avoid having headers.  If you do have headers, make sure to exclude them while reading.
- Read data from the file into an array or a set of variables

like so:

```
# using an array - works great if we have a variable number of columns
while IFS=, read -r -a row; do
  # ${row[0]} => column1, ${row[1]} => column2 and so on
  # process data
done < input.dat

# using variables - works great if we have a fixed set of variables
while IFS=, read -r column1 column2 column3; do
  # process data
done < input.dat
```

See also: [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks thats perfect, Im just wondering if there is anyway to achieve the same without using an external file?

Comment: You can pipe your data extractor's output directly into the while loop.